# PrestaShop: Remove the navigation bar (breadcrumb) in all pages

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to remove the navigation bar entirely from  all my PrestaShop pages 
I m using PrestaShop 1.6.3 version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way is to comment the entire code in `breadcrumb.tpl`. Otherwise you can comment the row that includes the `breadcrumb.tpl` in `header.tpl` of your template :)

EDIT:

To find this file you will go in:
`prestashop/themes/your-template/`

Use `{* *}` to comment the code

In `header.tpl` find this line of code `{include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"}`

Answer (score 0):

Open file /themes/your-theme/header.tpl and comment this line:

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"}
```

*To comment just add `{*` `*}`*:

```
{*include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"*}
```